# Why is the oscilloscope in Multisim software showing more voltage than the source?

Tags: diodes, rectifier, multisim

The Multisim oscilloscope shows around 13V peak despite the voltage source being 12V peak. I was expecting 12V. The diode voltage drop is set to 0.1v  when forward biased.

[image: A screenshot of simulation]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the green circles I've added below: -

[image]

You are using too big of a maximum time step in your simulation. Try lowering it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but how do I lower the time step? I'm new to this software.

Comment: I don't know I don't use multisim but I can recognize the symptoms.

Comment: Search the user's guide for *time step*, *timestep*, or *TMAX*. *TMAX* will find it quickly in: https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371590b.pdf

Comment: The solution is lurking around the time step, I lowered it and I somehow managed to get the expected reading but lowering time step welcomed me with another problem. Oscilloscope displayed values only for the first quarter period and it didn't display anything for the remaining time. But thank you guys I managed to complete my work although not smoothly.